# Template literals and parentheses-less function calls

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals, tagged-templates

I recently learned that ES6 allows to make function calls without parentheses when using a template literal as a parameter. E.g.

```
showstring`Hello World`;
```

After reading a few articles on this functionality, however, I have come away with scant information as to the logic behind how JS handles these calls.

After playing around with some permutations of my code, I am still struggling to piece together the pattern of how a template literal is broken down inside the function when one calls it that way.

```js
const showstring = (str) => {
  console.log(str);
}
showstring`Hello World`;
```

What happens in the above code is straightforward, the string literal is received as an array where the first and only element is the string.

Where it gets a bit confusing is once I start using expressions inside the template. E.g.

```js
const showstring = (str, ...values) => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(values)
}
const name = 'John'
showstring`Hello World ${name} ${name} ${1 + 2} and more`;
```

So it looks like the `...values` part destructures all the expressions. But why, then, does the `str` array have empty strings in those spots?

I just don't fully grasp the pattern it follows here. Can someone explain this feature? Or perhaps point me to a good article?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the second code snippet, these are logged:

```js
// str
[
  "Hello World ",
  " ",
  " ",
  " and more"
]

// values
[
  "John",
  "John",
  3
]
```

If by those "empty strings" you mean the 2nd and 3rd item of the `str` array, they are not empty strings; they are strings with a single space. They come from the spaces between the expressions in the template literal:

```js
showstring`Hello World ${name} ${name} ${1 + 2} and more`;
//                            ^       ^
```

---

When a template literal is preceded by an expression – in this case `showstring` – it's called a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates).

In your `showstring` function, `str` contains always one more item than the `values` array. E.g. take a look at what these log:

```js
const showstring = (str, ...values) => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(values)
}
const name = 'John'
showstring``;
showstring`${name}`;
showstring`Hello ${name}!`;
```

This isn't specific to your function; this is how tagged templates work. From the [*Tagged templates* section in the book *JavaScript for impatient programmers (ES2020 edition)*](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/ch_template-literals.html#tagged-templates):

> The function before the first backtick is called a *tag function*.
> Its arguments are:
>
> - *Template strings* (first argument): an Array with the text fragments surrounding the interpolations `${}`.
> - *Substitutions* (remaining arguments): the interpolated values.

---

About your comment:

> Interestingly though,
> that single space will always remain a single space
> no matter how many spaces you put between the expressions
> when calling the function.
> Any idea why it trims to just one space?

This doesn't seem to be the case. This logs a string with three spaces:

```js
const showstring = (str, ...values) => {
  console.log(str);
  console.log(values)
}
const name = 'John'
showstring`Hello ${name}   ${name}!`;
```

Were you maybe printing the results to the DOM? Multiple spaces are shown as only one unless you are using `<pre>` or `white-space: pre;` or something similar, so it might seem that the results are trimmed to just one space.

Comment: Interestingly though, that single space will always remain a single space no matter how many spaces you put between the expressions when calling the function. Any idea why it trims to just one space?

Comment: @codemonkey This doesn't seem to be the case. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great breakdown. Indeed I was using playcode.io to test the multiple space scenario and I have little doubt that it is because of how it prints results to the DOM. Good point.

Comment: Can you suggest any clever uses for this feature? Although very interesting, it seems completely superfluous to me.

Comment: @codemonkey Check the second link (the book chapter) in my answer, it has some examples and also more info about template literals and tagged templates. See also e.g. [Awesome Tagged Templates](https://github.com/kay-is/awesome-tagged-templates) and [`common-tags`](https://github.com/zspecza/common-tags).